# I'm getting AXIOS error code 404 when trying to post data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, backend

I am trying to send the data on the form on my website to the database using axios, but every time I encounter this error, I tried multiple solutions but the result is always the same. Using the fetch method, I can retrieve the data I entered manually from the same database, but I cannot send data.
My app.js and server.js file's below

[image]
[[image]]

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useState } from "react";
const instance = axios.create();
export default function AddUser() {

  const [user, setUser] = useState({
    id: "",
    name: "",
    username: "",
    email: "",
  });

  const { name, username, email, id } = user;

  const onInputChange = (e) => {
    setUser({ ...user, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  const onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    return instance.post("http://127.0.0.1:8081/felice", user);
  };

  return (

    <form onSubmit={(e) => onSubmit(e)}>
      <label htmlFor="ID">
        ID
      </label>
      <input
        type={"text"}
        name="id"
        value={id}
        onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)}
      />
      <label htmlFor="Name">
        Name
      </label>
      <input
        type={"text"}
        name="name"
        value={name}
        onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)}
      />
      <label htmlFor="Username">
        Username
      </label>
      <input
        type={"text"}
        name="username"
        value={username}
        onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)}
      />
      <label htmlFor="Email">
        E-mail
      </label>
      <input
        type={"text"}
        name="email"
        value={email}
        onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)}
      />
      <button type="submit">
        Submit
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

```
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express()
app.use(cors())

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "127.0.0.1",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "felice"
})

app.get('/felice', (re, res)=> {
    const sql = "SELECT * FROM reservations";
    db.query(sql, (err, data)=> {
        if(err) return res.json(err);
        return res.json(data);
    })
})

app.listen(8081, () => {
    console.log("working");
})
```

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
    at C:\Users\Utku\Desktop\reservation-software-felice\backend\server.js:24:21
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Utku\Desktop\reservation-software-felice\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\Utku\Desktop\reservation-software-felice\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Utku\Desktop\reservation-software-felice\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Utku\Desktop\reservation-software-felice\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\Utku\Desktop\reservation-software-felice\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15 
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Utku\Desktop\reservation-software-felice\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
    at next (C:\Users\Utku\Desktop\reservation-software-felice\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
    at cors (C:\Users\Utku\Desktop\reservation-software-felice\backend\node_modules\cors\lib\index.js:188:7)     
    at C:\Users\Utku\Desktop\reservation-software-felice\backend\node_modules\cors\lib\index.js:224:17
```

Comment: the URL where you sending request is not exist, just verify if you are sending a correct request. You can check in the network

Comment: URL is working in my localhost i can get data from the url

Comment: can you upload the screenshot for the network request?

Comment: I uploaded the screenshot

Answer (score -2, accepted):

1. post method should have the data parameter in your case (i.e. `return instance.post("http://127.0.0.1:8081/felice", user);`)
2. Given the back-end snippet you uploaded, it's clear now that the reason for your 404 is that you haven't written a post function on the backend side (you only wrote the get method).
3. Please install the body-parser package using `npm install body-parser`
4. The import it using `const bodyParser = require('body-parser')`
5. Then add the following code after `app.use(cors())`

```js
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

7. And you can use the following code as a post handler:

```js
app.post('/felice', (req, res)=> {
    var id=req.body.id;
    var name=req.body.name;
    var username=req.body.username;
    var email=req.body.email;
    const sql = `INSERT INTO reservations (ID, name, username,email) VALUES ('${id}', '${name}', '${username}', '${email}');`;
    db.query(sql, (err, data)=> {
        if(err) return res.json(err);
        return res.json(data);
    })
})
```

Comment: I uploaded my server.js code and screenshot from url

Comment: please check my latest update

Comment: Oh, i see. But i dont know how to write a post function can you help a little more?

Comment: Sure, please check my next update

Comment: have you tested the post handler, is it working for you?

Comment: I tested but but this time i get this error 
AxiosError: Request failed with status code 500

Comment: please upload the error log from the server side

Comment: I uploaded to question

Comment: I meant the error log from the node server console, not the browser console

Comment: Oh, sorry for that. I uploaded again.

Comment: please change (re, res) to (req, res)

Comment: I updated the error with change

Comment: have you added the user variable to the post function on the frontend

Comment: The current version of my front-end file is above

Comment: Please check my updates, I added the body-parser import